# JSON retorna STRING ao invés de ARRAY

Tags: php, javascript, json

O código a seguir esta retornando uma array como string e portanto não consigo distribuir os dados para popular o flot chart.

O

Código PHP:

```
<?php

include_once("config.php");

$viagemid = $_POST['id'];
$results_array = array();

$sql = "SELECT adiantamento AS 'Antecipado' FROM viagem WHERE viagemid = $viagemid";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

    array_push($results_array, $row);
}

$sql = "SELECT SUM(vl_desp) as 'Despesas' FROM despesas WHERE viagemid = $viagemid";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

    array_push($results_array, $row);
}


$sql = "SELECT SUM(venda.vl_venda * venda.qtd) AS 'Venda SP' FROM venda WHERE venda.viagemid = $viagemid AND venda.ufid = 1";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

    array_push($results_array, $row);
}

$sql = "SELECT SUM(venda.vl_venda * venda.qtd) AS 'Venda local' FROM venda WHERE venda.viagemid = $viagemid AND venda.ufid = 2";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

    array_push($results_array, $row);
}



$string = "[[0,".$results_array[0]['Antecipado']."],[1,".$results_array[1]['Despesas']."],[2,".$results_array[2]['Venda SP']."],[3,".$results_array[3]['Venda local']."]]";


var_dump(json_decode(serialize($results_array), true));

?>
```

O JS:

```
    $(function() {

        $.post('chart_data.php', {id:<?php echo $viagemid; ?>}, function(data) {

            alert(data);
            var d1 = [[0,data],[1,data],[2,data],[3,data]];

            alert(d1);

        var barOptions = {
            series: {
                bars: {
                    show: true,
                    barWidth: 0.6,
                    fill: true,
                    align:'center',
                    fillColor: {
                        colors: [{
                            opacity: 0.8
                        }, {
                            opacity: 0.8
                        }]
                    }
                }
            },
            xaxis: {
                tickDecimals: 0,
                ticks:[[0,'Adiantamento'],[1,'Despesas'],[2,'Venda SP'],[3,'Venda local']]
            },
            colors: ["#ffbb00"], 
            grid: {
                color: "#999999",
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true,
                tickColor: "#D4D4D4",
                borderWidth:0
            },
            legend: {
                show: false
            },
            tooltip: true,
            tooltipOpts: {
                content: "%x: %y"
            }

        };
        var barData = {
            label: "bar",
            data: d1
        };
        $.plot($("#flot-bar-chart"), [barData], barOptions);

    });

        //return false;
});
```

Comment: Qual o retorno do `JSON`?

Comment: Estás a usar o `var_dump` para enviar para o JavaScript? Tira e coloca `echo`.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade após usar o var_dump(json_decode( ele da erro (json_decode expects parameter 1 to be string), então usei serialize() para converter para string e então retornou NULL e com echo ele retorna "[{"Antecipado":"30000"},{"Despesas":"18256.61"},{"Venda SP":"13080"},{"Venda local":"18021.5"}]"

Comment: Por que estás serializando? Não há necessidade, funcionou normalmente dando `json_decode` nesse retorno, veja no [ideone](https://ideone.com/rIwLyJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alguns pontos a considerar:

1) Não há necessidade de executar `4` `querys` e percorrê-las repetidamente com `while`. Você pode fazer apenas um `select` e utilizar o `fetch_all` do `mysqli`.

2) Como não explicou qual a intenção do uso do `serialize`, não vejo utilidade nele para isso.

```
include_once("config.php");

$viagemid = $_POST['id'];
$results_array = array();

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT
(SELECT adiantamento  FROM viagem WHERE viagemid = {$viagemid}) AS 'Antecipado',
(SELECT SUM(vl_desp) FROM despesas WHERE viagemid = {$viagemid}) AS 'Despesas',
(SELECT SUM(venda.vl_venda * venda.qtd) FROM venda WHERE venda.viagemid = {$viagemid} AND venda.ufid = 1) AS 'Venda SP',
(SELECT SUM(venda.vl_venda * venda.qtd) FROM venda WHERE venda.viagemid = {$viagemid} AND venda.ufid = 2) AS 'Venda local' 
SQL;

$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
$result = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);


echo json_encode($result, true);
```

Em sua chamada `ajax`, informe o `dataType: JSON`, veja as opções [aqui](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) :

Altere de:

```
$.post('chart_data.php', {id:<?php echo $viagemid; ?>}, function(data) {
```

Para:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'chart_data.php',
  data: {id:<?php echo $viagemid; ?>},
  dataType: "json",
  sucess: function(data) {
     alert(data);
        var d1 = [[0,data],[1,data],[2,data],[3,data]];

        alert(d1);

    var barOptions = {
        series: {
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.6,
                fill: true,
                align:'center',
                fillColor: {
                    colors: [{
                        opacity: 0.8
                    }, {
                        opacity: 0.8
                    }]
                }
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            tickDecimals: 0,
            ticks:[[0,'Adiantamento'],[1,'Despesas'],[2,'Venda SP'],[3,'Venda local']]
        },
        colors: ["#ffbb00"], 
        grid: {
            color: "#999999",
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true,
            tickColor: "#D4D4D4",
            borderWidth:0
        },
        legend: {
            show: false
        },
        tooltip: true,
        tooltipOpts: {
            content: "%x: %y"
        }

    };
    var barData = {
        label: "bar",
        data: d1
    };
    $.plot($("#flot-bar-chart"), [barData], barOptions);
  }
});
```

Comment: Obrigado Marcelo, porém ele continua retornando json_decode expects parameter 1 to be string.

E obrigado também pela organização do código, fiz varias querys para ir testando.

Comment: Corrigi a resposta, a função correta é `json_encode`. Faça o teste novamente.

Comment: Estava pesquisando e cai no json_encode, por coincidencia. Ele passou para o JS, porém tudo em uma unica string: 
[{"Antecipado":null,"Despesas":"6000","Venda SP":"14240","Venda local":"900"}]

Comment: Mas o formato está correto, não? Você deve adicionar o `type: JSON` na sua `ajax request` ou dar um `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Sim, é exatamente esse. Pode me descrever a sintaxe do JSON.parse? Estou lendo sobre isso nesse momento mas  estou com dificuldades para adaptar para o meu código.

Comment: Veja o exemplo que inseri na resposta.

Comment: Marcelo, muito obrigado pela ajuda. 
Eu acabei não mudando para Ajax como sugeriu (não consegui) mas aprendi a usar o JSON.parse e consegui converter para objeto.

Comment: Ótimo que tenha entendido o funcionamento e resolvido o problema.